# How to build device-tree overlays using DKMS?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, device-tree, dkms

I am trying to build a device-tree overlay using DKMS for a running kernel (4.4). My naive Makefile is as follows:

```
PWD := $(shell pwd)

dtbo-y += my-awsome-overlay.dtbo
targets += $(dtbo-y)

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/${kernelver}/build M=$(PWD) dtbs

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/${kernelver}/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.13-v7+'
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/modules.order: Permission denied
```

How can I fix it? It should be possible without root privileges, right?

How would a *standard* Makefile for building dt overlays using DKMS look like?

**Edit:** I think I have solved the problem, see below. However, a qualified answer would still be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `my-awsome-overlay.dtbo` to `my-awsome.dtbo`. Assuming the dts file name is `my-awsome-overlay.dts`.
2. Add `always := $(dtbo-y)`.
3. Invoke `make` without a target (remove `dtbs`).

Here is a working Makefile:

```
PWD := $(shell pwd)

dtbo-y += my-awsome.dtbo

targets += $(dtbo-y)    
always  := $(dtbo-y)

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/${kernelver}/build M=$(PWD)

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/${kernelver}/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Would be awesome to see the dkms.conf for an overlay as well.

Comment: @ensonic see here: https://github.com/taudac/taudac-driver-dkms/blob/overlay/dkms.conf

Comment: I think this will only work on the Rasp Pi kernels, is that right? I'd be interested in solving this for stock (or Debian) kernels as well. Still, thanks for this as a hint on how to get started!